# How can I check if a document has an object with the same key and value as an array of objects?

Tags: content-management-system, sanity, groq

I have a product document, and each product has an array of "productFilters", with this shape:

```
{
  name: "Filter Name",
  value: "Filter Value",
}
```

For my params, I have an array of key/value pairs, and I need to check if any of the product filters match the params.

```
[{ rpm: "3800" }]
```

How can I write a query that does this? I'm able to do something very simple like this if I have one param, but I have an array of them and don't know how to iterate over it or compare the two arrays:

```
"products": *[_type == "product"
              && defined(filterValues)
              && $searchName in filterValues[].name
              && $searchValue in filterValues[].value
             ]
```